# How to ge the average of two matrices on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I have 2 matrices,

```
a= [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];
```

and

```
b= [13 14 15; 16 17 18; 19 20 21; 22 23 24];
```

How can I make the average of these 2 matrices and store the values in another matrix "C" on Matlab?

The value of C will be,

```
c= [(1+13)/2 (2+14)/2 (3+15)/2; (4+16)/2 (5+17)/2 (6+18)/2;...]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `c = (a + b) / 2`?

Answer (score 4):

You would do:

```
c = (a+b)/2
```

This will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to stack the matrices on top of each other in 3D, then find the average along the third dimension:

```
c = mean(cat(3, a, b), 3);
```